# How to set dynamically some fields in inner objects and only them, to be serialized?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Let's have some json message:

```
{
    league: {
        name: A,
        score: 4528
        team:{
            name: NY
            score: 356
        }
    }
    team:{
        name: CA
        score: 455
    }
}
```

Really the message is much greater and contains hundreds of fields, often with same simple names in  different structures.

We have many clients, and every one has his set of fields he wants to see. Even more, these sets of fields can be changed at run.

In GSON `ExclusionStrategy` works well if I have JSON message with globally unique names. There are some answers here on SO with that info.

```
public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
    return !f.getName().equals(requiredName);
}
```

It even can be used if we want to distinct league.score and team.score. By using `f.getDeclaringClass()`. (That can be found on SO, too.) But using it I have a container class, not JSON hierarchy object such as `FieldAttributes f` and so, I can't go further and get the container of the container.

**But if I want to distinct `league.team.score` and `root.team.score`, even that method won't help.**

I am working with JSON messages with GSON now. But i will gladly see a solution in any JAVA technology